# Installation error - Craft.uppercaseFirst is not a function

Tags: install, installation

I get two errors upon installing the latest build 2.3.2641. The first is a slide function for the "Create Your Account" window and the second is a more severe error of `TypeError:Craft.uppercaseFirst is not a function` which prevents installation and causes the busy gif to work continuosly as if something was about to occur.

php version 5.4.39
MySQL Version   10.0.17-MariaDB

Comment: Did you attempt to re-download and/or -upload the core files?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like some files were not uploaded correctly to your server, or are corrupt/missing from your Craft download.

Download a fresh copy of Craft from http://buildwithcraft.com and swap out your existing `craft/app` folder with the new, freshly downloaded `craft/app` folder.

Comment: Indeed it was a corrupt install. I was using Filezilla and it encountered a conflict with a duplicate file - which is odd considering it was a fresh install. I elected to skip when I should have overwritten.